# sox soundexchange - how do you stop recording when there is silence longer than 20 sec?

Tags: command-line, audio-recording, sox

**I cannot get sox to stop recording when silence occurs.**

I've have successfully gotten the result I needed when using sox with input output files:

`sox original.mp3 trimmed.mp3 silence 1 0.3 1% 1 20.0 1%`

sox starts recording after the first noise of 0.3 seconds, then records until 20 seconds of silence are detected.

**Issue: When I try to do the same with parameter -d (to record from the default device, a microphone, not an input file) - it doesn't work, the recording never stops (even though there is absolute silence):**

`sox -d temp_new.mp3 silence 1 0.3 1% 1 20.0 1%`

Thank you!

**Added info:**
I am not using a microphone, but a **virtual** audio cable that routes system noise to the sox app. The respective machine does not have a microphone, so there cannot be local background noise in the recording.

Comment: I'm sure you have a sound-proof studio and the perfect microphone. But have you considered increasing the threshold to, say, 20%? Just as an experiment, to rule out that slight chance of being bugged by background noise?

Comment: BTW, it wasn't clear to me whether `original.mp3` was a recording made using the same microphone setup, or a totally unrelated audio file.

Comment: Thank you @RuudHelderman - I edited the post to make it more clear, I am using a virtual microphone to route system audio only.I did try to increase the threshold to 20% - same result.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering if silence detection would work if you would do it in 2 steps, i.e. first record without `silence` filter (manually stop after, say, one minute of silence), then use the resulting output file as input for a second call to sox _with_ silence filter. Will it trim the trailing silence down to 20 seconds or not? Note: I know that second step is identical to your earlier experiment `sox original.mp3 trimmed.mp3 silence 1 0.3 1% 1 20.0 1%`, but I still cannot tell from your story whether or not `original.mp3` is a raw recording taken from the same audio source.

Comment: Thank you,@RuudHelderman , two step process does work: 

`sox -d full.mp3 trim 0 00:45:00 silence 1 0.3 1%` 
=> records 45 min audio into full.mp3

then remove silence at the end: 

`sox full.mp3 full_trimmed.mp3 reverse silence 1 0.3 1% reverse`

This works fine - but if the original full.mp3 contains say 15 min of silence, I have to wait the 15 min of silence until I can do the trimming. I'd love to have the sox command just cut off the recording once silence of a certain length is detected.  It's simply much more efficient.

P.S all files record from the same virtual audio source